# Spark Java API: How to convert JavaRDD to RDD type

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to convert code written using `Dataframe` into `DataSet` API.
The problem is that I have JavaRDD created as :

```
final JavaRDD<String> abcJavaRdd= jsc.textFile("/path/to/textfile");
```

But the `createDataset` method of sqlContext class expect `RDD<T>` type rather than `JavaRDD<T>` type.

```
SQLContext sqlc = new SQLContext(jsc);
....
....
Encoder<Abc> abcEncoder= Encoders.bean(Abc.class);
Dataset<Abc> abcDataset= sqlc.createDataset(abcJavaRdd, abcEncoder);
```

The last line in the above code does not work.
I want to know how to create '`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD`' type from '`org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD`' type?

I am using Java 1.8 with apache spark 1.6.1 on mapr cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through API, I found the answer.

The `org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD` class exposes a static method to convert a `JavaRDD` type of object into `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD` which is accepted by `createDataset` method of `SQLContext` class.

```
Encoder<Abc> abcEncoder= Encoders.bean(Abc.class);
Dataset<Abc> abcDataset= sqlc.createDataset(JavaRDD.toRDD(abcJavaRdd), abcEncoder);
```

Another way is to call `rdd()` method on `abcJavaRdd`. i.e. `abcJavaRdd.rdd()`